# Batch Create and Rename from list

Tags: batch-file

txt files from a list i have,i can create the files no problem but stuck when i try to add sequencial numbering(1,2,3...)to the start of the files.

Here what i have:

```
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do echo %%i > %%i.txt
```

here some of the names on the list for example:

```
Crabs Versus Skeletons
The Quest For Braccus Rex
The Teleporter Pyramids
The Wishing Brother
A Voice in the Wilderness
And about 100 more
```

It creates the .txt files from the list no problems,but what i want is:

```
1 Crabs Versus Skeletons
2 The Quest For Braccus Rex
3 The Teleporter Pyramids
4 The Wishing Brother
5 A Voice in the Wilderness
6..and so on...
```

with the sequential numbers at the start of the name,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And so far, you have tried...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a in ('find /v /n "" list.txt') do >"%%a %%b.txt" echo(%%a %%b
```

Omit the "%%a " from whichever (filename or text-content) if required

Comment: sorry i keep getting "tokens=1* was unexpected also "delims=[]" was unexpected

Answer (score 1):

Another way :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "$c="

for /f "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do (
   set /a $c+=1 
   echo !$c! %%i > %%i.txt
)
```

Comment: this created the .txt files from the list but with the sequencial numbers inside the created .txt

Comment: Just put the `!$c!` before the `%%i.txt`

Comment: thnakyou,it worked too i just modified a little to include space "!$c! %%i.txt"